# Magento custom options for dynamically priced bundled product (no price manipulation)

Tags: magento-1, bundled-product, custom-options

Is there a way to add a custom option that does not manipulate the price, to a dynamically priced bundled product.

For example: If we want to sell a suit which is a bundled product, made up of pants and jacket, and we want the customer to select arbitrary data for the pants (for example, color), but we don't want those selections to affect the price in any way, how would we do this?

What would you suggest as the best way, to add this arbitrary data (read: extra data that doesn't affect price)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the Stock Magento.  Have you shopped around for extensions? Here's one that might work for what your trying to do http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html

Comment: A link to a module might be helpful for the person who originally asked the question, but @dbernsons answer actually provides some information for those of us arriving here down the road. -1.

Answer (score 2):

An old question I know, but just in case others stumble across this, there's a way of accomplishing this by adding the custom options on the bundle product itself.

Normally Magento won't let you save these for a dynamically priced bundle, but all it takes is a minor modification to the code.

I used the following blog post as a basis for my changes:
http://amirshakya.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/custom-options-on-a-bundle-product-in-dynamic-pricing/

Although please, please whatever you do, do NOT modify the core files as the blog author has done. Move the file from **app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Observer.php** to **/app/code/local/Mage/Bundle/Model/Observer.php** and then make the change.

Using this method, you can add custom options to the bundle product. As far as I'm aware this only works for options that don't modify the price, but from the question I believe that should be sufficient.

Comment: this is one of the solutions i used for awhile (+1) thanks for posting